Button not working when I tap/click but works when I tab through and hit enter
As you can see here I have a button called launchCreateNewRewardActivityBtn but it doesn't work when I tap it. I have set up other buttons in the code and it seems to me like the code is the same for each of my other activities. So, to me, it seems like it should be working... Let me know if you need any more code or insight on this topic.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RewardsFrag"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create new reward"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/launchCreateNewRewardActivityBtn"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50sp"
        android:onClick="createNewReward"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rewardsRecView"
        android:padding="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

Here is the on click listener ... as you can see it is setup correctly; so I think atleast. However it doesn't actually work unless I tab and then hit enter. What do I do?
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // Initializations
        launchCreateNewRewardActivityBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.launchCreateNewRewardActivityBtn);
        rewardsRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rewardsRecView);
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelperRewards(getContext());

        // Initialize the adapter
        adapter = new RewardsRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), dbHelper);

        adapter.setRewards(rewards);
        rewardsRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        rewardsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        // Set the onClickListener on the button
        launchCreateNewRewardActivityBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), CreateNewHabitActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, requestCodeForCreateNewRewardActivityCall);
            }
        });
    }


I just set the layout above for the recyclerView to the button. I guess the recyclerview was over top of the button so I couldn't press it. Makes sense... Heres the updated code
android:layout_above="@+id/launchCreateNewRewardActivityBtn"/>

